# Adding google analitycs to an android (gradle) project

Tags: android, gradle

My `/build.gradle` file:

```
....
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics:v3-rev99-1.19.0'
}
```

And a source file:

```
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker
```

where **analitics** is highlighted in red. Why isn't it found?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following instead:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
```

Assuming you are trying to use V4. See
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Follow Before you begin section.

Comment: "Be sure to edit the file for your application module. " - which one is it: in root or in /app folder?

Comment: You should update your build.grade in the app folder. Also you are connected to the internet while trying to do this correct? Any gradle build error in the log? What do you have for "repository"?

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

Check for this in build.grade in the main folder.